Can a chrome extension scrape for urls, then access those urls to scrape their html files?
I'm learning about scraping and chrome extensions at the moment. So I want to build one that scrape s the UberEats websites. It grabs the links to restaurants menu's and accesses their html file to scrape the name of restaurants.
This is just proof of concept to know if I can even scrape the html in a url in the first place. My main goal is to do the scraping when the user searches of a dish on UberEats website where it loads a bunch of restaurant, and my extensions scrapes the html of the url of those restaurants to find matching dishes.
I don't want to use puppeteer or selenium since they require a separate backend, where my extension need to access using an api. I don't have a server nor do I want to host one. So I want to do all of this on the extension.
So far, I got the part where it extract the URLs, and now I need to access those URLs. I learned about background scripts, and fetch(). I tried using fetch to get a response from the URLs I scraped and then return the html to be scraped later on.
But it didn't work and my catch error keeps getting returning these for every link I try to scape. It doesn't show up on the console but on the chrome://extensions.
Error scraping data for URL: https://www.ubereats.com/ca/store/woking-dragon-chop-suey-house-langley/zzIphhS4XhaTOx7uDFoHsQ ReferenceError: error is not defined
Context
background.js
Stack Trace
background.js:55 (anonymous function)
 }
        } catch (error) {
55            console.error('Error scraping data for URL:', fullURL, error);
        }
    }
    return storeNames;
}

If there is better approach then what i've done, please let me know thank you.
The rest of my code:
Manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Food Delivery Scraper",
  "description": "Scrape & Summarize Food Delivery Data",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "scripting"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
      "https://www.ubereats.com/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
      {
          "matches": ["https://www.ubereats.com/*"], 
          "js": ["popup.js"],
          "run_at": "document_idle"
      }
  ]
}


background.js
function parseLink(URL) {
    const baseURL = "https://www.ubereats.com";
    return baseURL + URL;
}

async function fetchHTML(fullURL) {
    fetch(fullURL)

    .then(response => {
        // Checking if the response is successful
        if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        // Parsing the response as text
        console.log(response.text());
    })
    .then(html => {
        // Once HTML is retrieved, you can scrape the data from it
        return html;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('There was a problem with the fetch operation:', error);
    }); throw error; // Rethrow to handle outside
}

function scrapeMenuData(html) {
    const tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
    tempDiv.innerHTML = html;
    const storeTitleElement = tempDiv.querySelector('h1[data-testid="store-title-summary"]');
    if (storeTitleElement) {
        const storeTitle = storeTitleElement.textContent.trim();
        console.log('Store Title:', storeTitle);
        return storeTitle;
    } else {
        console.log('Store Title element not found');
        return null;
    }
}

async function scrapeLinks(cards) {
    const storeNames = [];
    for (const card of cards) {
        const fullURL = parseLink(card.url);
        try {
            console.log("await fetchHTML");
            const html = await fetchHTML(fullURL);
            console.log("scrapeMenuData");
            const storeTitle = scrapeMenuData(html);
            if (storeTitle) {
                storeNames.push(storeTitle);
            }
        } catch (error) {
55:**            console.error('Error scraping data for URL:', fullURL, error);**
        }
    }
    return storeNames;
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.action === "scrapeData") {
            scrapeLinks(request.cards).then(storeNames => {
                sendResponse({storeNames: storeNames});
            });
            return true; // Indicates response will be sent asynchronously
        }
    }
);

popup.js
// popup.js

document.getElementById('scrapeApp').addEventListener('click', async () => {
    let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});

    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: {tabId: tab.id},
        function: getCardsData,
    }, (injectionResults) => {
        for (const frameResult of injectionResults) {
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
                action: "scrapeData",
                cards: frameResult.result
            }, response => {
                console.log('Scraped Names:', response.storeNames);
                updateUI(response.storeNames);
            });
        }
    });
});

function getCardsData() {
    const cards = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-testid="store-card"][href]')).map(card => ({
        url: card.getAttribute('href')
    }));
    return cards;
}

function updateUI(storeNames) {
    const main = document.querySelector('main');
    main.innerHTML = ''; // Clear previous results
    storeNames.forEach(name => {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.textContent = name;
        main.appendChild(div);
    });
}


throw error; // Rethrow to handle outside should be INSIDE the catch block - you also need to return fetch(fullURL)...... otherwise const html will be undefined

This is using a hammer to drive in a screw: don't use an extension for this, use a headless browser (selenium, playwright, etc). Using the right tool for the job makes things a lot easier.

ManifestV3 can't use DOM (document) in the background script. Do it in the offscreen document, where you can fetch and process the URL or (if the site generates its content using a js script) add an iframe to that site and use a content script inside to process it.
